# How can I set a property of a DropShadowEffect via a Trigger in a ControlTemplate?

Tags: wpf, triggers, controltemplate

I have a `Button` `ControlTemplate` and I'm trying to modify a `DropShadowEffect` on a `Border` by using a `Trigger`. Here is my Xaml:

```
<Button.Template>
  <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
    <Border x:Name="ButtonBorder" Margin="10" CornerRadius="5" Background="Gray">
      <Border.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="5" x:Name="BorderEffect" />
      </Border.Effect>
      <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="Button.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="ButtonBorder" Value="LightGray" />
      </Trigger>
      <Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="ButtonBorder" Value="13,13,7,7" />
        <!-- this is where I get the error -->
        <Setter Property="ShadowDepth" TargetName="BorderEffect" Value="2" />
      </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
  </ControlTemplate>
</Button.Template>
```

I get an error stating that the `BorderEffect` cannot be found.
I have also tried:

```
<Setter Property="Effect.ShadowDepth" TargetName="ButtonBorder" Value="2" />
```

But I also get an error telling me that the property `ShadowDepth` could not be found on the object of type `Effect` (because it's using the base class instead of `DropShadowEffect`)

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can set the Effect as a whole in the setter.value

```
 <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="ButtonBorder" Value="13,13,7,7" />
    <Setter Property="Effect" TargetName="ButtonBorder" >
      <Setter.Value>
         <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="2" />
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Trigger>
```

Comment: Yep, that's what I ended up using, but I which there was a way to just modify the property I need... Thanks :-)