# Casting type right in XAML code?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm a WPF newbie, my problem is I want to cast some property type to another right in XAML code like this:

```
//I want to cast Effect to DropShadowEffect to access it's ShadowDepth
<Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
   <Setter Property="Effect.ShadowDepth" Value="0.5"/>
</Trigger>
```

But `ShadowDepth` is not accessible, `Effect` should be casted to `DropShadowEffect` first. Could you show me any solution in which I can do the casting right in XAML code. If it's impossible, a `TypeConverter` in code behind would be OK. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you need to cast? I never needed to cast anything in XAML. You can even write DataContext.MyProperty, even while DataContext is of type object. What is the error you are facing? Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749882/how-can-i-set-a-property-of-a-dropshadoweffect-via-a-trigger-in-a-controltemplat) can help you.

Comment: @dowhilefor I think in fact it's not really a casting, I just need a way to access the `ShadowDepth` property of the `Effect` property. My `Button` has `Effect` property assigned with an instance of a `DropShadowEffect`. I want to change the `ShadowDepth` when the button is pressed using `Trigger`. As you can see there seems no way    to give the correct path of the `Property`.

Comment: @dowhilefor the link you suggested gives me a solution which I currently used before. It doesn't matter much if `DropShadowEffect` has only the property `ShadowDepth` to care about, but it does have more than that and recreating an instance with only different `ShadowDepth` from the old one is not so convenient. If there is a simpler solution, I can also apply it to other kinds of `Effect` such as `BlurEffect`...

Answer (score 0):

I see two possibilities:

1. Recreate your `DropShadowEffect` in your setter, recreating the object's `Effect`.
2. Give your `DropShadowEffect` a name, and reference the object directly using `TargetName`:

   `<Setter TargetName="dropShadow" Property="ShadowDepth" Value="0.5" />`

Comment: I used the first method but it's not so convenient. However for the second approach, we can't name a `DropShadowEffect` by `Name="..."`, we can name it by `x:Name="..."` however the parser said it couldn't find any element with the name I gave in the visual tree.